# How to access this properties

Tags: php

I executed a function and it returns an object. The var_dump of the object can be seen at:

view-source:http://quemfazsite.com.br/temp/boleto/teste.php

I want to access the property `id` inside of `_attributes`. How do I do that?

I tried

```
$returned_value -> _attributes -> id
```

but it shows NULL. What am I doing wrong?

```
object(Iugu_Invoice)#7 (2) {
["_attributes":protected]=>
array(51) {
["id"]=>
string(32) "B2EC65C567244A69BBFD4513CC5D460E"
["due_date"]=>
string(10) "02/09/2015"
["currency"]=>
string(3) "BRL"
["discount_cents"]=>
NULL
["email"]=>
string(15) "teste@teste.com"
["items_total_cents"]=>
int(1000)
["notification_url"]=>
NULL
["return_url"]=>
NULL
["status"]=>
string(7) "pending"
["tax_cents"]=>
NULL
["updated_at"]=>
string(25) "2015-08-28T11:32:09-03:00"
["total_cents"]=>
int(1000)
["total_paid_cents"]=>
int(0)
["paid_at"]=>
NULL
["taxes_paid_cents"]=>
NULL
["paid_cents"]=>
NULL
["cc_emails"]=>
NULL
["financial_return_date"]=>
NULL
["payable_with"]=>
string(9) "bank_slip"
["overpaid_cents"]=>
NULL
["secure_id"]=>
string(41) "b2ec65c5-6724-4a69-bbfd-4513cc5d460e-f4a3"
["secure_url"]=>
string(67) "https://iugu.com/invoices/b2ec65c5-6724-4a69-bbfd-4513cc5d460e-f4a3"
["customer_id"]=>
NULL
["customer_ref"]=>
NULL
["customer_name"]=>
NULL
["user_id"]=>
NULL
["total"]=>
string(8) "R$ 10,00"
["taxes_paid"]=>
string(7) "R$ 0,00"
["total_paid"]=>
string(7) "R$ 0,00"
["total_overpaid"]=>
string(7) "R$ 0,00"
["fines_on_occurrence_day"]=>
NULL
["total_on_occurrence_day"]=>
NULL
["fines_on_occurrence_day_cents"]=>
NULL
["total_on_occurrence_day_cents"]=>
NULL
["advance_fee"]=>
NULL
["paid"]=>
string(7) "R$ 0,00"
["interest"]=>
NULL
["discount"]=>
NULL
["created_at"]=>
string(14) "28/08, 11:32 h"
["refundable"]=>
NULL
["installments"]=>
NULL
["transaction_number"]=>
int(1111)
["payment_method"]=>
NULL
["created_at_iso"]=>
string(25) "2015-08-28T11:32:09-03:00"
["updated_at_iso"]=>
string(25) "2015-08-28T11:32:09-03:00"
["financial_return_dates"]=>
NULL
["bank_slip"]=>
object(stdClass)#3 (3) {
["digitable_line"]=>
string(47) "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
["barcode_data"]=>
string(44) "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
["barcode"]=>
string(75) "https://iugu.com/invoices/barcode/b2ec65c5-6724-4a69-bbfd-4513cc5d460e-f4a3"
}
["items"]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
array(3) {
["description"]=>
string(32) "Serviço Digital CÓD. 873923675"
["quantity"]=>
string(1) "1"
["price_cents"]=>
string(4) "1000"
}
}
["variables"]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
object(stdClass)#5 (3) {
["id"]=>
string(32) "B16E017E3D124AA38C2B8F97E2723C5B"
["variable"]=>
string(31) "payment_data.transaction_number"
["value"]=>
string(4) "1111"
}
}
["custom_variables"]=>
array(0) {
}
["logs"]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
object(stdClass)#6 (4) {
["id"]=>
string(32) "4FC3CF74C5184DBE9C3F7B2DC421E308"
["description"]=>
string(26) "Email de Lembrete enviado!"
["notes"]=>
string(50) "Lembrete enviado com sucesso para: teste@teste.com"
["created_at"]=>
string(14) "28/08, 11:32 h"
}
}
}
["_unsavedAttributes":protected]=>
array(4) {
["due_date"]=>
int(1)
["email"]=>
int(1)
["payable_with"]=>
int(1)
["items"]=>
int(1)
}
}
```

Comment: Try to minimize the amount of code that still identifies your problem. Please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

First of all the variable **_attributes** is **protected**, you will need a getter method. As you cannot access the Iugu_Invoice class to add it, you can extend the class:

```
use Namespace\To\Iugu_Invoice;
class MyIugu_Invoice extends Iugu_Invoice{
    public function getAttributes(){
       return $this->_attributes
    }
}
```

Please bear in mind to use the real namespace in the code above. If you do not use namespaces just forget that bit. Then you need to use MyIugu_Invoice instead of Iugu_Invoice.
Also, _attributes is an array not an Object, so you will need to do:

```
$attributes = $returned_value->getAttributes();
$id = $attributes['id'];
```

Comment: Well, in the description pasted it says `["_attributes":protected]=>array(51)` which means that _attributes is a protected array of 51 elements

Comment: I got the error Call to undefined method Iugu_Invoice::getAttributes()

Comment: @amandanovaes did you create the method getAttributes as I specified it? It needs to be created just like that in the Iugu_Invoice class description

Comment: @Juancho Ramone I dont have access to change the Iugu_Invoice class. I can only use it. Is there any other way I can access its properties? I am almost giving up. I will end up using print_r($returned_value,true) to get the string and use regex to parse it. It's terrible doing this but I see no other way to get this data...

Comment: thank you so much Juancho. I just dont know what to replace in the "Namespace\To\Iugu_Invoice". What should I put in there? Should I use Iugu_Invoice?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88220/discussion-between-juancho-ramone-and-amandanovaes).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the id is in an array, not in a class property. 
Try this:

```
$returned_value->_attributes["id"]
```

And as mentioned you can't access that array because it's protected, if you can't add a getter in the class (as you mentioned) you have to inherit from that class, and add a getter.

Comment: this didnt work. How does someone create e library that I can use but cant access the properties? Why does print_r work fine and can access the contents without any getter and setter?

Comment: Yeah as all the guys said, you'll need a getter. If you can't change that class try to inherit it!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
echo $returned_value["id"];
```

or this:

```
$attr = (object) array_shift($returned_value);
echo $attr->id;
```

Comment: If you have problem to get object (private or protected) into $returned_value->_attributes try this:

`$attr = (object) array_shift($returned_value);`
`echo $attr->id;`